# Include dependency on a shared object in my c++ source within a JNI project for Android

Tags: android, maven, java-native-interface, dependencies, shared-libraries

I apologize if I'm not using the correct terms, but I'm pretty new to Maven and JNI.

Here is my problem.

I have an Android project (A) which relies on JNI to use c++ sources. The c++ code is in an independent project (A-native) which build a .so library (A-android.so). The java wrapper, which uses the native functions, is within a separate project (A-java) which depends on A-android.so. A-java is built using the maven-compiler-plugin.

This project works fine and I have no issue in defining the dependencies between the two projects in the pom for A-java.

Now I'm creating a new project (B) which has the exact same structure. It is composed of two parts: one with the c++ code (B-native) which generate the .so file (B-android.so); one with the java wrapper (B-java) which depend on the B-android.so.

Part of B-native is duplicated code from the old project so I would like to include A-android.so among the dependencies in the pom.xml for B-native when building B-android.so and reuse the objects defined in A-native.

I've tried to include A-android.so in the dependencies in B-native pom but still when I run mvn clean install I have error because the classes defined in A-native are not found. Note that I've included the .h file in my B-native include directory.

I would really appreciate is someone can explain me the correct way to handle this kind of dependencies.

Thanks!

Update:
Here are the pom for the two projects that build the c++ code. As you can see they are identical except that the one for project B adds project A in the dependencies

Project A

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>so</packaging>

    <artifactId>ProjectA-Native</artifactId>
    <name>ProjectA-Native</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Maven Compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <!-- Use java 1.6 -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>libs</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Project B

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectB-Native</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>so</packaging>

    <artifactId>ProjectB-Native</artifactId>
    <name>ProjectB-Native</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectA-Native</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>so</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <!-- Use java 1.6 -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>libs</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                     <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: posting the pom files may be useful

Comment: Hi ben75. Sorry for the late reply I've noticed your comment only now.